# jquery function one per load/refresh

Tags: jquery, function

```
 $(".avatar-box1").mouseleave(function(){
        $( ".avatar-box1" ).effect( "bounce", "slow" );

    });
```

hello i need to run this effect only once per load/refresh the page.
Grateful for any advice

Comment: http://www.sitepoint.com/types-document-ready/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use jQuery [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

```
 $(".avatar-box1").one("mouseleave", function(){
    $( ".avatar-box1" ).effect( "bounce", "slow" );
 });
```